# Comparing two DateTime .TimeOfDay if they crosses in any way. ASP C#

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core

After thinking round about two hours on it, i hope you guys can help me on this one.

I want to build is a calendar-like system where the user isn’t able to add an entry if another entry falls or crosses in the same .TimeOfDay.

So I want to compare two dates (DateTime)
To be more specific: the date is just the same just different .TimeofDay

Example:

```
(Existing entry)
DateTime dateStart:    05/05/2021 17:00
DateTime  dateEnd:     05/05/2021 18:00

(User wants to add this:)
DateTime  compareStart:  05/05/2021 16:30
DateTime  compareEnd:    05/05/2021 17:15
```

What i want to archieve is to compare if the compareStart + compareEnd crosses the dateStart and dateEnd in any possible way.

SideNote:

compareStart could be 05/05/2021 17:25 and compareEnd could be 05/05/2021 18:30 etc.

It should be only possible to add an entry if there isn’t any any that falls or crosses existing ones.
I hope i’ve described my problem clear.

Any advises are welcome

thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four different overlapping cases that can occure (excuse my Paint skills)

And all of them four have the following in common:

`Existing.StartDate <= New.EndDateDate`
and `Existing.EndDate >= New.StartDate`

[image]

Simplified class:

```
public class Event
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

two events compared

```
bool isOverlapping = e1.StartDate <= e2.EndDate && e1.EndDate >= e2.StartDate;
```

or in a method for a real world example e.g. a calender with a list of existing events comparing with a new one before inserting

```
public boolAddEvent(List<Event> events, Event newEvent)
{
    if (!events.Any(x => x.StartDate <= newEvent.EndDate && x.EndDateDate >= newEvent.StartDate))
    {
        events.Add(newEvent);
        return true
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```